# Dynamic Lambda Expression inside an Expression Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Is it possible to use a dynamic Linq Expression inside a Query Expression?
Something like this:

```
from obj1 in ObjectSet1
let res = ObjectSet2.Where(* SomeExpression *)
where ...
select ...
```

I'm trying to build `Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>` Expression as for SomeExpression.

1. Is it possible to to use dynamic Linq Expression within the Expression Query or do I need to build the whole Expression tree from scratch?
2. How can I, if any, use obj1 when I'm building SomeExpression?

Note: I'm using Entity Framework, I can't use SomeExpression.Compile() within the expression tree.

Comment: I believe it is. Look here for more info (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) and here (http://naspinski.net/post/Writing-Dynamic-Linq-Queries-in-Linq-to-Entities.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, string predicate might help! I was wondering if it is possible to use the Expression builder? Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "obj1") doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not only possible, it's normal. Large expression trees can be generated from smaller trees (this is what LINQ does). You only have to pass in an `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>` to `Where()`.

You can see how in my reply to this other thread here - [replacing operator in Where clause Lambda with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207683/replacing-operator-in-where-clause-lambda-with-a-parameter/9209896#9209896) . The interesting part is in the `MakeWhereLambda` method.

Comment: Alright, how to use the query iterator inside the expression? I need to have access to obj1 (from above sample) in the new Expression. How do you define the ParameterExpression?

Comment: Hmmm... can't you just refer to it normally? Isn't it in your scope? 

P.S. It's not part of your expression as it's neither input nor output. It's a so called free variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting it to be completely dynamic, one possible option would be to use Expression Tree Serialization:

http://expressiontree.codeplex.com/

I started to use this a while back but that task got reprioritized, so I'm not sure how suitable it is for any given task.  That said, it looks pretty good...

Hope this helps.

Nate